# How to find steps in a vector (1d array, list) in Python?

Tags: python, list, vector

I want to get border of data in a list using python
For example I have this list :

```
a = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,1,1,1]
```

I want a code that return data borders. for example:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,1,1,1]
     ^       ^     ^         ^
b = get_border_index(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[0,4,7,12]
```

How can I implement `get_border_index(lst: list) -> list` function?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `def get_border_index(lst): return [0] + [i+1 for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] != lst[i+1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalable answer that also works for very long lists or arrays is to use [np.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). In that case you should avoid a for loop at all costs.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,1,1,1]

a = np.array(a)

# this is unequal 0 if there is a step
d = np.diff(a)

# boolean array where the steps are
is_step = d != 0

# get the indices of the steps (first one is trivial).
ics = np.where(is_step)

# get the first dimension and shift by one as you want
# the index of the element right of the step
ics_shift = ics[0] + 1

# and if you need a list
ics_list = ics_shift.tolist()

print(ics_list)
```

Comment: This is outputting `[4, 7, 12]` without the 0

Comment: As I wrote in the comments above that 0 is rather trivial. You could also add the index of the last entry then.

Comment: No, you can't add the last entry because the entry before have the same value and to avoid the first entry is not part of the request because if it was then you could wrote the solutin in one line by list comprehension.

Comment: I am not talking about step "second-to-last -> last", but last into the void. It's the same than with the first one, you just don't know the value before. so who is to say that there is a step :) That's basically forward or backward finite difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop with `enumerate`

```
def get_border_index(a):
    last_value = None
    result = []
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        if v != last_value:
             last_value = v
             result.append(i)
    return result
a = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,1,1,1]
b = get_border_index(a)
print(b)
```

Output

```
[0, 4, 7, 12]
```

This code will check if an element in the `a` list is different then the element before and if so it will append the index of the element to the result list.